# Running .ps1 Powershell from C# - Not Working

Tags: c#, powershell, selenium-webdriver, .net-core

This is not new for most here. I went through almost all posts from here and blogs. It doesn't error out.

***I am not getting any errors. If  I run PowerShell locally it works [expected to take screen shot], when running from C# it is not taking Screenshots.***

Installed all the required NuGet packages.
`using System.Management.Automation;`

I am trying to run .ps1 from c# but not working. Powershell takes a screenshot and stores it in a provided path.

**Locally I am running .ps1 as below and it takes a screenshot. But from c# it doesn't.**

```
C:\source\Hooks\TestScreenCapture.ps1 -ScreenShotPath C:\source\Hooks\testy.png
```

This function takes a screenshot when runs from selenium.

I have written a c# code to run it.

**Script located at:**

```
var psScript = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.Replace("bin\\Debug\\netcoreapp3.1", "Hooks"), "TestScreenCapture.ps1");
```

**1st Approach:**

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                FileName = "powershell.exe",
                Arguments = $"-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -file \"{psScript}\" -ScreenShotPath \"{screenShotFullPath}\"",
                UseShellExecute = false
            };
            Process.Start(startInfo);
```

**2nd Approach**

```
var powerShell = PowerShell.Create();
powerShell
          .AddScript($"\"{psScript}\"", false)
          .AddParameter("ScreenShotFullPath", screenShotFullPath)
          .Invoke();
```

**3rd Approach**

```
var powerShell = PowerShell.Create();
powerShell
          .AddScript(@"& {psScript} -ScreenShotFullPath {screenShotFullPath}")
          .Invoke();
```

*I tried running PowerShell code from my C# just to check if c# is working or not and it works.*

```
string criteria = "system*";
PowerShellInst.AddScript("Get-Service -DisplayName " + criteria);
Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = PowerShellInst.Invoke();
foreach (PSObject obj in PSOutput)
{
    if (obj != null)
    {
        Console.Write(obj.Properties["Status"].Value.ToString() + " - ");                
        Console.WriteLine(obj.Properties["DisplayName"].Value.ToString());
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Done");
```

**Issues seem PowerShell to take a screenshot from c# is not working.**

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: just updated the post.

Comment: what is your exception/error?   have you any?

Answer (score 1):

First, set `bypass` execution policy.

```
InitialSessionState iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
        iss.ExecutionPolicy = ExecutionPolicy.Bypass;
        iss.LanguageMode = PSLanguageMode.FullLanguage;
        iss.ThrowOnRunspaceOpenError = true;
PowerShell.Create(iss)
```

Second, run `Start-Transcript` command to begin transcription.

`AddCommand(@"Start-Transcript").AddParameter(@"Path", @"S:\out.txt").Invoke()`